# SQL position of row(ranking system) WITHOUT same rank for two records

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm trying to create a ranking system for my website, however as a lot of the records have same number of points, they all have same rank, is there a way to avoid this?

currently have

```
$conn = $db->query("SELECT COUNT( * ) +1 AS 'position' FROM tv WHERE points > ( SELECT points FROM tv WHERE id ={$data['id']} )"); 
$d = $db->fetch_array($conn); 
echo $d['position'];
```

And DB structure

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Edited below,

What I'm doing right now is getting records by lets say

```
SELECT * FROM tv WHERE type = 1
```

Now I run a while loop, and I need to make myself a function that will get the rank, but it would make sure that the ranks aren't duplicate
How would I go about making a ranking system that doesn't have same ranking for two records? lets say if the points count is the same, it would order them by ID and get their position? or something like that? Thank you!

Comment: it is not very clear what you are asking, and what is your goal. Are you asking about some ranking algorithm, or you have an algorithm but you have trouble implement it in sql???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MS SQL Server 2008R2, you can use the `RANK` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

If you are using MySQL, you can look at one of the below options:

http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

http://www.fromdual.ch/ranking-mysql-results

Comment: He has a `mysql` tag on the question bro.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `ORDER BY`. Applying on multiple columns is as simple as comma delimiting them: `ORDER BY points, id DESC` will sort by points and if the points are the same, it will sort by id.

Here's your SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM tv WHERE points > ( SELECT points FROM tv WHERE id ={$data['id']} ) ORDER BY points, id DESC
```

Documentation to support this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: still says the same for each one, could it be because Im running a Db array fetchign already(a loop) and then try to get the position with a new connection?

Comment: Ya I've updated the query to be an actual fetch instead of a count. Try this directly in your SQL editor

Comment: I attempted using 
SELECT *
FROM tv
WHERE points > (
SELECT points
FROM tv
WHERE id =256 )
ORDER BY points, id DESC

However this returned 12 rows? Tried adding num_rows and running in my loop, just said 12 for all of them, Im guessing this is because a lot of them have 0 points, this is what I need to sort out somehow, that even if they got 0 points, they would still have different ranks

Answer (score 1):

```
select @rnk:=@rnk+1 as rnk,id,name,points
    from table,(select @rnk:=0) as r order by points desc,id
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Database vendors have added special functions to their products to do this,  but you can also do it with straight SQL:

```
Select *, 1 + 
   (Select Count(*) From myTable
    Where ColName < t.ColName) Rank
From MyTable t
```

or to avoid giving records with the same value of colName the same rank, (This requires a key)

```
Select *, 1 + 
   (Select Count(Distinct KeyCol) 
    From myTable
    Where ColName < t.ColName or
      (ColName = t.ColName And KeyCol < t.KeyCol)) Rank
From MyTable t
```